# Adding an iPhone Project to an existing Github Project

Tags: xcode, git

I'm working on a bit of documentation code for an API project.

Someone else already has an existing github account where some people have already submitted a few projects. I will call it {http://github.com/monkeyhouse/}

I've created a project in Xcode (iPhone app), and have that stored under my normal Xcode git, which is backed up everything is fine.

What is the right bit of git foo that I need to put Xcode Project into 
{http://github.com/monkeyhouse/examples/iPhoneClient}

I've tried creating a symbolic link to the project on my machine and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a common way to do what you're wanting to do on Github:

1. Fork http://github.com/monkeyhouse/ under your own Github account.
2. Clone your forked version of the repo to your development machine.
3. Make the modifications you want directly to your cloned repo (e.g., don't use a symlink), adding examples/iPhoneClient to the local repo, and commit the changes.
4. Push your changes to your public Github fork of http://github.com/monkeyhouse/.
5. Submit a pull request with http://github.com/monkeyhouse/ to have them bring in the changes you pushed to your forked version if they're happy with them.